# Performance when executing stored procedure using DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

Is there a performance difference when executing stored procedures from Entity Framework? I tried to do some testing, but I get similar results, so I want to make sure I decide to use better approach.

One way it to add the stored procedure in EDM, and second way is to call

```
content.Database.SqlQuery("sp_Name", params)
```

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/execute-stored-procedure-using-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: Is there performance difference compared to calling sprocs by ADO?